# Polymorphism in WCF and external classes

Tags: c#, wcf, polymorphism

i have a base class in an external DLL `WorkerTemplate`. Two classes inherit from it `ExecSQLWorker` and `CopyWorker`.

I know want to build an WCF Service that just has `WorkerTemplate` as method parameter.

I tried it like that:

```
namespace PQWService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    [ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypesProvider))]
    public interface IPQWService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void EnqueueWorker(WorkerTemplate[] worker);
    }

    internal static class KnownTypesProvider
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
        {
            return new Type[] { typeof(ExecSQLWorker), typeof(CopyWorker) };
        }
    }
}
```

Still i get following Exception when calling `EnqueueWorker(worker)`:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:worker. The InnerException message was 'Type 'DV_BII30.ExecSQLWorker' with data contract name 'ExecSQLWorker:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DV_BII30' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'DV_BII30.ExecSQLWorker' with data contract name 'ExecSQLWorker:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DV_BII30' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteArrayOfWorkerTemplateToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameter(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameters(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.SerializeBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, Object[] parameters, Object returnValue, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
```

I get that the serializer expects not ExecSQLWorker but WorkerTemplate Object. I thought with the `[ServiceKnowntype]` Attribute i told WCF that it shall accept also `ExecSQLWorker` and `CopyWorker`.

Unfortunately the class `WorkerTemplate` comes from the DLL so i cannot just add the class as `[DataContract]`.

Comment: Instead of trying to make WCF behave like a method call to another class in the application, remember it's a *service* endpoint that transfers data objects back and forth. These *must* be well known in advance, defined in their schemas, otherwise clients won't be able to use the service. You can't *not* add the `DataContract` attribute, that's what tells WCF which class is your DTO.

Comment: You should create your own data classes even if they match exactly with those of another library, and adorn them with the proper attributes. Use Automapper to map from one class to the other